# AzureML Studio Prompt Flow- "No Module named 'azureml.fsspec'

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-promptflow

I am trying to work with file data in Azure ML prompt flow and resorted to this article:

[Access data from Azure cloud storage during interactive development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-data-interactive?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=adls)

It said to run this command in my runtime compute instance to install azureml.fsspec and mltable:
`pip install -U azureml-fsspec mltable`

[After everything was installed, I kept getting this error whenever I ran the python prompt flow step that had fsspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giq89.jpg)

===============================

I actually had to install fsspec and mltable with specific versions: fsspec 1.0.0 and mltable 1.3.0. This is because the updated versions doesn't work with the azureml-dataprep library together. This is what happened with the updated versions:

```
ERROR: azureml-dataset-runtime 1.51.0 has requirement azureml-dataprep<4.11.0a,>=4.10.0a, but you'll have azureml-dataprep 4.11.1 which is incompatible.
```

Or these two errors:

```
ERROR: mltable 1.4.1 has requirement azureml-dataprep[parquet]<4.12.0a,>=4.11.1, but you'll have azureml-dataprep 4.10.9 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azureml-fsspec 1.1.1 has requirement azureml-dataprep<4.12.0a,>=4.11.1, but you'll have azureml-dataprep 4.10.9 which is incompatible.
```

So apparently dataprep version has to be <4.11 for dataset-runtime but 4.11.1 for fsspec and mltable.

=============================

So I have fixed that issue by using older versions of azureml-fsspec and mltable but I still get the same error saying that there's no fsspec module whenever I run the python prompt flow step.

Has anyone ever run into this issue or know how to solve it?

Comment: Can you provide more details such as: 
what specific task you're trying to do?
Are you running the code in azureml notebook?
And other relevant details which can help in reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RishabhM I am currently having compute instance issues so I can't show the python step I was trying to run. But I was trying to run this line of code inside of the prompt flow python step:

`from azureml.fsspec import AzureMachineLearningFileSystem`

But kept getting the "No module named azureml.fsspec" error. Even though I installed it in the compute instance terminal.

Comment: Welcome to AzureML! I have faced several bugs while I was trying to use Azure ML SDK v1. For PromptFlow, I will wait for it to come out of preview mode.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same issue. I have seen this issue only on Mac with non-intel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided information, I have reproduced the issue.

[image]

When we are creating runtime for Prompt flow it will assign a `default runtime environment` which doesn't contain the required package.

To solve this, you can install the packages using `subprocess`.

```py
import subprocess
package_name = "azureml-fsspec"
subprocess.check_call(["python", "-m", "pip", "install", package_name])
```

[image]

With this I was able to resolve the issue.

[image]

Another possible solution is to use custom environment with required packages.
For more details, please refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/prompt-flow/how-to-create-manage-runtime?view=azureml-api-2#update-runtime-from-ui).